# Limit the number of running jobs in SLURM

Tags: bash, slurm

I am queuing multiple jobs in SLURM. Can I limit the number of parallel running jobs in slurm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are not the administrator, your can `hold` some jobs if you do not want them all to start at the same time, with `scontrol hold <JOBID>`, and you can delay the submission of some jobs with `sbatch --begin=YYYY-MM-DD`.

Also, if it is a job array, you can limit the number of jobs in the array that are concurrently running with for instance `--array=1:100%25` to have 100 jobs in the array but only 25 of them running.

Finally, you can use the `--dependency=singleton` option that will only allow one of a set of jobs with the same `--job-name` to be running at a time. If you choose three names and distribute those names to all your jobs and use that option, you are effectively restricting yourself to 3 running jobs max.

Comment: when you `hold` a job I guess you have to manually `unhold` it to allow it to run right ? Is it possible to make it automatically `unhold` whenever a running job ends ?

Comment: @zwlayer yes you have to `unhold` them. You can put that at the end of your submission script, or write some script to monitor what is happening, but then I would suggest considering the use of a workflow management tool such as FireWorks for instance.

Answer (score 12):

According to the SLURM Resource Limits [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html), you can limit the total number of jobs that you can run for an association/qos with the `MaxJobs` parameter.  As a reminder, an association is a combination of cluster, account, user name and (optional) partition name.

You should be able to do something similar to:

```
sacctmgr modify user <userid> account=<account_name> set MaxJobs=10
```

I found [this presentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm_ug_2012/SUG_Oct2012_DBD.pdf) to be very helpful in case you have more questions.

Answer (score 6):

According to [SLURM documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html), `--array=0-15%4` (**-** sign and not **:**) will limit the number of simultaneously running tasks from this job array to 4

I wrote **test.sbatch**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sbatch
#
#SBATCH -J a
#SBATCH -p campus
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -o %A_%a.output

mkdir test${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}

# sleep for up to 10 minutes to see them running in squeue and 
# different times to check that the number of parallel jobs remain constant
RANGE=600; number=$RANDOM; let "number %= $RANGE"; echo "$number"

sleep $number
```

and run it with `sbatch --array=1-15%4 test.sbatch`

Jobs run as expected (always 4 in parallel) and just create directories and kept running for *$number* seconds.

Appreciate comments and suggestions.

Comment: Upvote for giving an example and detailed report of the `%` syntax. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If your jobs are relatively similar you can use the slurm array functions.  I had been trying to figure this out for a while and found this solution at 
https://docs.id.unibe.ch/ubelix/job-management-with-slurm/array-jobs-with-slurm

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#SBATCH --mail-type=NONE
#SBATCH --array=1-419%25  # Submit 419 tasks with with only 25 of them running at any time

#contains the list of 419 commands I want to run
cmd_file=s1List_170519.txt

cmd_line=$(cat $cmd_file | awk -v var=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} 'NR==var {print $1}')    # Get first argument

$cmd_line  #may need to be piped to bash
```

Comment: The link is unfortunately dead.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer, in my case, I needed to run a maximum number of jobs per node, and I needed to do it exclusively using srun (not sbatch). The way I resolved this problem was to use use these three flags together: `--nodename=<nodename> --dependency=singleton --job-name=<uniquename>_<nodename>`.

First I create an array with `x` unique names, where the length of that array is the maximum number of jobs I want to run per node. Second, I create an array with all the node names I want to use. Finally I combine these two arrays in a cyclic fashion, that is, I append the node name to the unique name, and I make sure that the value for `--nodename` matches the values of the appended nodename. The result is that of limiting the maximum number of jobs that run on each node, rather than to limit the max number of jobs. In my case I needed to distribute it this way mainly due to memory constraints on each node.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished by using a while loop to monitor the user's job queue. This counts the squeue header too, so this will prevent job from being submitted if there are already 6 running or in queue.

```
while [ $( squeue -u $(whoami) | wc -l) -gt 6 ]; do 
    sleep 10; done; sbatch script.sh
```